# how to create and display item.cs while the program is running?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to create items in a ListView to be displayed in a View, how do I go about doing this?

Code-Behinds and the other View's ViewModel, are basically empty, except for a Binding Context and a manually created item in the ViewModel for viewing and testing stuff.

I have been trying for a while and this is basically me admitting defeat, I am sorry for literally copy-pasting my code, but I am getting desperate, if you can, please do explain the solution and thank you very much

Model - Item.cs is

```
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfQuantity { get; set; }

    }
```

Xaml for creating items V

```
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Padding="10">
            <Button Text="Button"
                Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" 
                    Clicked="Mover_Clicked"/>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" 
                  ColumnSpacing="3"
                  RowSpacing="3"
                  Padding="3"   
                  HeightRequest="200">
                    
                    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Name"  
                           BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NewItem.Name}" />
                    
                    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Description" 
                           Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NewItem.Description}"/>
                    
                    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Quantity"
                           Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NewItem.Quantity}"/>
                    
                    <Entry Placeholder="Enter Type of Quantity"
                           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NewItem.TypeOfQuantity}"/>
                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Xaml for Displaying items V

```
        <viewmodels:ViewModelBase/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
               HasUnevenRows="True"
               SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Item">
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Text="Delete" ></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Text="Edit" ></MenuItem>
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <Grid Padding="20">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="15">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                    <Image HeightRequest="90" 
                                           Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                </Frame>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label
                                           WidthRequest="150"
                                           Text="{Binding Description}"
                                           FontSize="Large"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Label 
                                           WidthRequest="150"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           FontSize="Large"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Grid HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest=" 170" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                        <Label 
                                           Text="{Binding Quantity}"
                                           HorizontalOptions="End"
                                           FontSize="Large"/>
                                        <Label 
                                           Text="{Binding TypeOfQuantity}"
                                           FontSize="Large" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                        <Button HeightRequest="25" 
                                                WidthRequest="25"
                                           Text="+"
                                           FontSize="Large" Grid.Column="2"
                                                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"/>
                                        <Button HeightRequest="25"
                                           Text="-"
                                           FontSize="Large" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                             
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Header>
            <Button x:Name="Mover" Clicked="Mover_Clicked" Text="Add new"></Button>
        </ListView.Header>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModelBase  V

```
    {
         public ObservableRangeCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfQuantity { get; set; }
        public Item NewItem { get; set; }
        public ViewModelBase()
        {
            Items = new ObservableRangeCollection<Item>();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel for item creation(which inherits ViewModelBase) V

````
    {
           public Command ButtonCommand { set; get; }
      
        public ItemEntryPageViewModel()
        {
            ButtonCommand = new Command(AddItemCommand);
        }

        private void AddItemCommand(object obj)
        {
            Items.Add(NewItem);
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: What specifically are you are having a problem with?  Does your code compile?  Do you get errors or exceptions?  Have you looked at the Xamarin samples, like ToDo?

Comment: i dont get errors i just cannot implement it, i do not understand how to create the Item and add it to the ObservableRangeCollection with user input from the Entry elements while the program is running

Comment: I don't have time to write out a complete 10 page example for you.  That's why I suggest you look at the **many** available samples - build them, run them, look at how they work.  For your code specifically, you are already binding all of your entries to `NewItem` so that object should already be populated with the values you enter.  **But**, you need to initialize the object in the VM constructor in order for that to work.